# OkHttp3 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x2019

Tags: android, http, http-headers, okhttp

Why OKHttp prohibit some printable characters to be sent as header? I am writing an apps that publishes a http header. The apps crashed because [a right single quoted character](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x2019/index.html).

This is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x2019 at 358 in my-header value: test’s 
       at okhttp3.Headers.checkValue(Headers.java:272)
       at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:312)
       at okhttp3.Request$Builder.addHeader(Request.java:196)
...
```

This is the [OkHttp source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Headers.kt#L416) that throws the exception:

```
internal fun checkValue(value: String, name: String) {
      for (i in 0 until value.length) {
        val c = value[i]
        require(c == '\t' || c in '\u0020'..'\u007e') {
          format("Unexpected char %#04x at %d in %s value: %s", c.toInt(), i, name, value)
      }
   }
}
```

Seeing that source code, is that a standard to allow only character in this range `require(c == '\t' || c in '\u0020'..'\u007e')` for http header?

Comment: Could you please show the whole of your `my-header` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2016).

Because of the exist of `checkValue` method in `Okhttp`, your header can't contains invalid data.

So you need to encode your `my-header` 's value.

Answer (score 2):

this is the right way:
https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-headers/-builder/add-unsafe-non-ascii/
use the Headers.Builder method: **addUnsafeNonAscii(String key,String value)**

Comment: how and where to add this headers object?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to let go of non-ASCII data just to avoid this crash then I'd recommend using this extension function:

```
fun String.isAscii() = length == utf8Size().toInt()
```

Then wrap your header value in an if-else check, use the value if it's ascii, otherwise use an empty string or some default value.